# How to calculate log-frequency spectrogram efficiently?

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing, librosa, spectrogram

I'm trying to plot a spectrogram using matplotlib where the frequencies are spaced logarithmically so I can visualize music/piano notes. From what I've found on the web this was the "best way" to do it:

```
data, samplerate = librosa.load("demo.wav")

S = np.abs(librosa.stft(data))
S = librosa.amplitude_to_db(S, ref=np.max)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

img = librosa.display.specshow(S, y_axis='log', x_axis='time',
                               sr=samplerate, ax=ax)
ax.set(title='Linear-frequency power spectrogram')
ax.label_outer()
plt.show()
```

and this works fine but the problem is that it takes a while and it's very uneffifient because librosa.stft() calculates all the frequency bins equally spaced and specshow(yaxis="log") obviously just maps the important frequencies so it looks logarithmic when its displayed. This leads to a lot of unused frequencies. Is there any way to make the notes fit the bins at the start so it's calculated much quicker and efficiently? It doesn't have to be using librosa.

Comment: This is a signal processing or statistics question and would get better response in those forums

Comment: To optimize, you can try: downsample, increase hop size, change to float32. Write your own stft that uses faster fft, use some multiprocessing

Comment: librosa.load(...., sr=None) - will make it much faster, if your file is not already 22kHz (rare)

Comment: The other slow part is usually plotting. Choosing a smaller n_fft is the easiest fix for that. Or compute a chromagram - it uses STFT internally, but output is a smaller set of bins, which will be faster to plot

Answer (score 1):

An FFT is O(NLogN), with very efficient and optimized implementations available.  So computing a log scaled frequency transform would require less memory, but would likely still be O(NLogN) without as efficient an available implementation as simply rescaling FFT results.